# Why does this linq query fail when I change the select clause to select new Model

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model

Why does this query work:

```
var rooms = from m in db.Rooms
                      where
                      m.FK_HotelID == id
                      select m;

            return View(rooms.ToList());
```

but this query (which I generated from a program called 'Linqer') seemingly fails?

```
var rooms = from m in db.Rooms
                      where
                      m.FK_HotelID == id
                      select new Room
                      {
                          RoomID = m.RoomID,
                          RoomNumber = m.RoomNumber,
                          RoomType = m.RoomType,
                          FK_HotelID = m.FK_HotelID
                      };

            return View(rooms.ToList());
```

I need help in getting the query to return a `List` of `Room` objects.
I don't think I can use an anonymous type or a DTO Model for the query because the View requires objects of the type  `Room`.  The query does return results in the Linqer program but when I try to get this view in my VS2013 Project, I get the following error message:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: The entity or complex type
>   'HotelApp.Models.Room' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities
>   query.

P.S, Here is my Room class for reference:

```
public partial class Room
{
    public Room()
    {
        Bookings = new HashSet<Booking>();
    }
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
    public int? FK_HotelID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public virtual Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Because you cannot create the same object in the query (unless you were to add `.ToList()` before the `select`). Create a view model containing the proeprties you need and project the query into that - `select new RommViewModel { ..... }`

Comment: Maybe you just want to turn off proxy creation for your db context or query with `AsNoTracking()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `LINQ To SQL` here which means, that query is translated to `SQL` that has no idea about your custom types.

```
    var rooms = (from m in db.Rooms
                      where
                      m.FK_HotelID == id
                      select m).ToList();

    var roomsVm = from m in rooms select new Room
                      {
                          RoomID = m.RoomID,
                          RoomNumber = m.RoomNumber,
                          RoomType = m.RoomType,
                          FK_HotelID = m.FK_HotelID
                      };

            return View(roomsVm.ToList());
```

What happens here is:

1) The first query goes to SQL and finds all the rooms you need.

2) Then it is translated to the List of C# objects.

3) The second query at this point is using `LINQ To Objects` and therefore can use your custom model.

---

Better solution for you would be to create a `ViewModel` that would contain all the fields you need sth like:

```
public class RoomViewModel {
    public int RoomId {get;set;}
    public string RoomNumber {get;set;}
    public string HotelName {get;set;}
//and all other properties you need on your View
}
```

then map your `DTO` to this new `ViewModel`:

```
var roomsVm = from m in rooms select new RoomViewModel
                          {
                              RoomId = m.RoomID,
                              RoomNumber = m.RoomNumber,
                              HotelName = m.Hotel.HotelName
                              //and other properties
                          };

                return View(roomsVm.ToList());
```

Comment: In your second query it gives an error:  "The type or namespace name 'rooms' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Answer edited. I just messed up with linq syntax. sorry.

Comment: Works almost perfectly now but in the view, `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hotel.HotelName)` shows a blank, though the `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hotel.HotelName)` works. The view is using the model `@model IEnumerable<HotelApp.Models.Room>`.

Comment: you need to map all the properties in `select new Room` section. As you can see the `Hotel` property is not set at all. Additionally depending how your `EF` is configured you may need to `Include` that property in the first query. I hope that mapping will be enough though.

Comment: Ok, but no such mapping is required in the first query but is required in the second one. Could you please explain why that is so? Is this possibly because the query is using 'LINQ To Objects' ?

Comment: LINQ to SQL translates everything to SQL queries. SQL is not aware of your types, so you can't ask it to do that mapping for you.

Comment: @MadOX in last code section, i think, `select new Room` should be replaced with `select new RoomViewModel`..

Comment: Same issue, but that didn't had any issue on EF6 we previously used on ASP.NET, the new EF that bundled with ASP.NET Core, is so full of bugs and errors toward what we thought

Answer (score 0):

That's cause `Room` is one of your mapped entity and projecting to a mapped entity is not allowed. You will have to use a DTO or project to an anonymous type.